# Convert array of enums to array of its representative strings

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, enums

I need an `Array` (or `Set`) extension method that can quickly convert an array of `Enum: String` values to an array of its actual `String` values. How would I go about that?

E.g. I have:

```
enum Scope: String
{
    case appPrivate = "app-private"
    case appLimited = "app-limited"
    case appPublic = "app-public"
}

let scopes: Set<Scope> = [.appPrivate, .appLimited, .appPublic]
```

Then I would need to get an array/set of `["app-private", "app-limited", "app-public"]` at a later point (e.g. to send to server endpoint).

Comment: Hint: `map` and `rawValue`.

Comment: @maddy Ok but how about the generic Enum?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Please show what you've tried and how it performed.

Comment: Last time I remember SO used to be a helpful channel, not a homework site. If non-hardcore, complex code questions bother you then why not just ignore them?! :)

But if we all are just supposed to solve the problems for ourselves then I guess we won't need SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum Scope: String, CaseIterable {

  case appPrivate = "app-private"
  case appLimited = "app-limited"
  case appPublic = "app-public"
}

let array = Scope.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
print(array) //["app-private", "app-limited", "app-public"]
```

If you don't want to include all enum values and have the need to create an array of only a few enum values you can do something like this

```
let scopeArray: [Scope] = [.appLimited, .appPrivate]
print(scopeArray.map({$0.rawValue})) //["app-limited", "app-private"]
```

Comment: Cuts it for me, thanks! The critical part was `CaseIterable`.

Comment: @BadmintonCat Your comment to this answer and the other contradict each other. My reading of your question indicates that you do not need `CaseIterable`. The only part of this answer that answers the question you actually asked is the 2nd half and that doesn't need the use of `CaseIterable`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `CaseIterable` protocol
Take this example:

```
enum Scope: String, CaseIterable {
  case appPrivate = "app-private"
  case appLimited = "app-limited"
  case appPublic = "app-public"
}

let array = Scope.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
```

Comment: But this maps all enum values to an array, doesn't it? What I need is map the values that are found in a specific array of enums (as example above).

Comment: The above prints exactly what you're looking for in your question: 
`["app-private", "app-limited", "app-public"]` Can you clarify what you're looking for if this is not working for you?

Comment: @valosip True, I should have been more clear. I need the values of an array of any number of the enum values. That array might contain all or less or only one of the enum values.